# ¿Cómo validar fecha en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

Necesito saber cómo puedo validar una fecha ingresada en un input type date. Lo que deseo, es que si el usuario elige una fecha antigua me active un alert y si elige una fecha superior a la fecha actual me active otro. No incluyo código debido a que no tengo nada para la fecha. Ya logre validar el nombre entre otros datos. Solo necesito la fecha. ¿Alguien tiene una página web donde tenga algo similar a lo que necesito?

Comment: Agrega tu código por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Si es para backend puedes usar [JSONSchema](https://json-schema.org/learn/getting-started-step-by-step.html) realmente es increíble

Answer (score 1):

El nuevo estandar **HTML** incluye el campo tipo fecha `<input type="date">`, este tipo de campo cuenta con las propiedades `min="..."` y `max="..."` que permiten validar fechas en un rango dado, ademas cuenta con la propiedad `required` que obliga a rellenar el campo, a continuacion te dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo.

**Ejemplo:**

```html
<form>
 Ingrese una Fecha valida entre el 01-06-2019 al 31-07-2019
 <input type="date" name="fecha" min="2019-06-01" max="2019-07-31" required>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

No obstante de ser necesario estos rangos pueden ser modificardos dinamicamente a traves de `javascript`

**Ejemplo:**

```js
let date = new Date()
let day = date.getDate()
let month = date.getMonth() + 1
let year = date.getFullYear()

if ( day < 10 ) { day="0"+day }
if ( month < 10 ) { month="0"+month }

var elm = document.getElementsByName("fecha")[0];
elm.setAttribute('min',year+"-"+month+"-01");

elm.setAttribute('max',year+"-"+month+"-"+day);
```

```html
<form>
 Ingrese una Fecha valida del mes en Curso
 <input type="date" name="fecha" required>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Espero esto puede ilustrarte de como hacerlo ;))